# how to handle log(0) in javascript when trying to plot a graph

Tags: javascript, math

I am using this [regression package](https://github.com/Tom-Alexander/regression-js) which uses this calculation to return an array of points:

```
exponential(data, options) {
  const sum = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

  for (let n = 0; n < data.length; n++) {
    if (data[n][1] !== null) {
      sum[0] += data[n][0];
      sum[1] += data[n][1];
      sum[2] += data[n][0] * data[n][0] * data[n][1];
      sum[3] += data[n][1] * Math.log(data[n][1]);
      sum[4] += data[n][0] * data[n][1] * Math.log(data[n][1]);
      sum[5] += data[n][0] * data[n][1];
    }
```

The problem is that `Math.log(data[n][1])` might return `-Infinity` if `data[n][1]` is 0.

How would I handle this case.  My maths is failing me on this one.

Comment: What do you want to do when data[n][1] == 0? Skip the point altogether? (Or is that the question?)

Comment: Is there a default value I should use if this Is the case?

Comment: I don't know the range of numbers you are dealing with What if you just substitute `-100000000` for `log(0)` ?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this issue, you can add a constant value `c` to all the `data[n][1]` so that none of them are `0` anymore (which is basically shifting all the points by `c` units). If the package does the right thing, it should predict an equivalent polynomial, which is also shifted `c` units. So, you can modify that polynomial to get the actual one by subtracting `c` from it.

Now, you could simply ignore the points which have ordinate value `0`, because those points don't contribute to the `exponential` method. I just checked the source code and in the `exponential` method, whenever `data[n][0]` and `log(data[n][1])` are used, `data[n][1]` is multiplied to them, so when `data[n][1]` is `0`, it doesn't make any difference. But the problem is, it calls the `determinationCoefficient` method, which calculates the `mean` of all the `data[n][1]` values. So, if you don't use the points with `data[n][1] = 0`, it will get a different value for the `mean`. As a result, you might get a different outcome.

Now the question is, do you need the points with `0` ordinates? The package is written assuming the ordinates are not `0`. You might be overfitting by using such points.

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  0 is actually important because I am using it for this graph https://cutting.scot/covid-19 and 0 signifies that there was no difference in the amount of deaths from the day before

Comment: That's really nice. The package should have considered this corner case. Maybe you can report an issue there. It is indeed a bug on their side. But hope my first solution will help.

You can verify that it works by doing the same thing with a different data set where all points have non-zero ordinates. Then you can use the package on it without applying the shift to get the expected outcome, and then apply the constant shift, and verify that it returns the equivalent outcome.

Comment: it looks abandoned there are several issues mentioning it https://github.com/Tom-Alexander/regression-js/issues/46,  I would create a PR but I honestly do not know what the correct answer is here

Comment: and I don't think the PR would get looked at

Comment: At least for the `exponential` method, the correct approach will be to ignore the points which have ordinate `0`. If you simply write down all the equations mathematically, using the `summation` and  `x_i`, `y_i`, you will see, the points which have `y_i = 0`, actually doesn't contribute towards any calculation. For example, in the line 152, it does `Σ y_i*log(y_i)`. Now mathematically, when `y_i = 0`, the value of `y_i*log(y_i)` is also `0`, hence it's not changing the ultimate value of `sum[3]`. So, the PR just needs a condition checking on `y_i` just to avoid the error.